# jquery mobile style applies for whole project - why?

Tags: grails, jquery-mobile

I want only the landing page to be styled with Jquery. It´s a Login page, when the user logs in with his phone it should show the usual style

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

<html><!-- lol-->
<head>
<title>myApp/title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" cahrset="utf-8">


</script>
</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="start" data-theme="d">
<div data-role="header">

<a href="http://www.fhws.de" data-icon="check">Kontakt</a>
</div>
<div class="ui-body ui-body-d">
    <g:form controller="login" action="doLogin">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" name="userNameField" id="username" value="Matrikelnummer" /></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="password" name="passWordField" id="password" value="Passwort" /></div>
        </div>

            <input type="submit" data-theme="d" name="loginButton" id="login" value="Login" />

    </g:form>
</div>

</body>   
</html>
```

As you can see in the form Im using grails for the backend. My problem is, all the other pages show jquery mobile style too when I login via this page.  Why is it? Is ist because the import via "link" tag makes it global for the whole project? 
thanks in advance Daniel

edit: the page where you land after login (supposed to have normal style:)

```
  <%@ page import="groovy.sql.ExpandedVariable; iwinews.User; iwinews.Category" %>
  <html>
 <head>
<meta name="layout" content="layout"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var scroll_lock = false
    var more_url = '${createLink(action:"singleNewspost")}';
    var newsposts_by_category_url = '${createLink(action:"newspostsByCategory")}';
    var all_newsposts_url = '${createLink(action:"allNewsposts")}';
    var subscribed_newsposts_url = '${createLink(action:"subscribedNewsposts")}';
    var filter_shown_categories_url = '${createLink(action:"filterShownCategories")}';
    var search_url = '${createLink(action: "search")}';

    var filterTypes = {
        search : 0,
        category : 1,
        alle_kategorien : ${Category.ALLE_KATEGORIEN},
        meine_kategorien : ${Category.MEINE_KATEGORIEN}
    };

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>

 <content tag="search">
<div id="_searchbox">
    <input id="search"/></div>
  </content>

  <content tag="menu">
 <h6>News-Kategorien:</h6>
 <select id="kategorien_dropdown" class="grid_2">
    <option id="${Category.ALLE_KATEGORIEN}" ${selectedCategory == Category.ALLE_KATEGORIEN ? "selected=\"selected\"" : ""}>alle Kategorien</option>
    <option id="${Category.MEINE_KATEGORIEN}" ${selectedCategory == Category.MEINE_KATEGORIEN ? "selected=\"selected\"" : ""}>meine Kategorien</option>
</select>

<div id="filteredKategorien">
    <g:render template="filteredKategorienTemplate" model="${categories}"/>
</div>
</content>
```

edit: This is the head of the layout/layout.gsp file

```
<%@ page import="iwinews.REVISION; iwinews.CONSTANTS; iwinews.User; iwinews.Category" %>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title><g:layoutTitle default="${CONSTANTS.PAGE_TITLE} /></title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<link rel="shortcut icon"
      href="${resource(file: 'favicon.ico')}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'styles', file: 'reset.css')}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'styles', file: '960_12_col.css')}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'styles', file: 'default.css')}"/>


<g:javascript library="jquery"/>
<g:javascript library="jqModal"/>
<g:javascript library="jquery.cookie"/>
<g:javascript library="jquery.form"/>
<g:javascript library="application"/>


<g:layoutHead/>
```

Comment: can you show your other view, where it's applied also?

Comment: sure, give me a sec to format it on here, thanks.

Comment: i didnt create the page so it´s hard for me to figure out whats important on it. Basically: it´s a gsp page wich also loads templates in it. Also important: In firebug, it shows the same head (all jquery mobile imports) than the first (login-) page, altho it´s not in the source code.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you've added jquery-mobile into main layout (`layout/layout.gsp`) And your `login.gsp` page extends it (it's `<meta name="layout" content="layout"/>`)

It's better to make two layouts:

- `/views/layout/mobile.gsp` - for mobile pages
- `/views/layout/browser.gsp` - for standard pages

and extend just that layout that you need for current page.

You can read more about Grails layouts at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.4%20Layouts%20with%20Sitemesh

Comment: hmm can you explain why I added the jquery mobile into main layout? It´s actually a own gsp just called loginMobile.gsp

Comment: hm, you said that all gsps have same head, so i've decided you added into main layout. if not - i can't explain it :(

Comment: when I create a layout "mobile" and import it into the loginMobile page, and only there, the jquery Mobile style applies for the whole project again.

Comment: what layout you're importing from other pages at this case?

Comment: on the page where you land after loggin in, it´s still the content="layout", in my login page i do the same (with the meta tag) but content="mobile". this layout implements jquery mobile (only this one) hope its what you meant

Comment: and, your `/layout/layout.gsp` doesn't have jquery-mobile css/js. right?

Comment: I added the head of the layout/layout.jsp in my post

Answer (score 0):

Concerning:

> when I create a layout "mobile" and import it into the loginMobile page, and only there, the jquery Mobile style applies for the whole project again.

As far as I understand from the history of this question, might be due to the fact that ajax is enabled by default.

Have you tried to use the `data-ajax="false"` attribute, for instance on the submit link/button?

Comment: hey buddy thanks for your answer but this is a while ago. I dont work with JQM atm but thanks anyway :)